# Modal form initial field

Tags: jquery, django

In my app a have form to update item.

User updates it using dropdown fields. If there is no required value on dropdown he can add his own.

It is done through the popup bootstrap modal form. Problem is that if the modal form is submitted user is redirected to form view but all values that we had already entered disappears.

I'm not looking for ready solution but a hint how to make it, because I am learning and I would like to now how it should be done properly.

1. Clicking "new person" opens the modal form. I don't want to make use choose subsidiary twice as a person belongs to the subsidiary.

[image]

2. If the new user is added all values filled by user disappears because I'm redirecting from modal to the point where the user is starting the update.

[image]

The modal form opens when the user chooses a new person form dropdown list:

jQuery:

```
$("#id_salesPersonDistributor").change(function () {
     var url = $("#subsidiaryForm").attr("data-salesPersonsDistributorContact-url");  
     var salesPersonDistributorId = $(this).val(); 
     var id_sales = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");

     if (id_sales == "new") {
       $("#id_salesPersonDistributor").modalForm({
           formURL: "{% url 'new_sales_person_distibutor' VCIUpdate %}"
      });
     } else {
     $.ajax({                      
       url: url,                    
       data: {
         'salesPersonDistributor': salesPersonDistributorId      
       },
       success: function (data) {   
         $("#salesPersonsDistributorContact").html(data); 
       }
     });
   }
});
```

view.py

```
class NewSalesPersonDistributor(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'newsalespersondistributor.html'
    form_class = NewSalesPersonDistributor

    def get_success_url(self):
          VCInumber = self.kwargs['pk']
          return reverse_lazy('VCIUpdate', kwargs={'pk': VCInumber})
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" id="subsidiaryForm"  name="text" data-subsidiaries-url="{% url 'ajax_load_subsiriaies' %}" data-salesPersonsDistributor-url="{% url 'ajax_load_salesPersonsDistributor' %}" data-salesPersonsDistributorContact-url="{% url 'ajax_load_salesPersonsDistributorContact' %}" novalidate>
        <table class="table table-borderless table-condensed">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
      <input type="hidden" name="build" value="{{ VCIUpdate }}">,
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="save" />


<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content"></div>
      <input id="modalhidden" type="hidden" name="build2" value="">
    </div>
```

HTML of the modal form

```
<form method="post" action="">
   {% csrf_token %}

   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Dodaj przedstawiciela</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
   {% for field in form %}
     <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} invalid{% endif %}">
       <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
       {{ field }}
       {% for error in field.errors %}
         <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
       {% endfor %}
     </div>
   {% endfor %}
 </div>


  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn btn-primary">Create</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the method of your form / input.
Remove the type submit of your inputs and change your form to:

```
<form onsubmit="return null" />

<input id="submit" value="save" />
```

Comment: Using this I could avoid redirecting a user and make input to the database ?

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work in my example. I didn't even find any information about return null on submit.